# Ownership of NSString returned by reference from NSScanner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, reference, nsscanner

Is the 'reference returned' `NSString` from the methods:

- `scanString:intoString:`
- `scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:`
- `scanUpToString:intoString:`
- `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`

in the `NSScanner` class owned by the calling instance (retain count of 1 and **NOT** in the autorelease pool) or the `NSScanner` instance (retain count of 1 and in the autorelease pool)?

If it is the later would not the autorelease pool balloon in size if used to iterate over a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` parameter of

```
- (BOOL)scanString:(NSString *)string intoString:(NSString **)value;
```

is an "Indirect parameter" in the sense of [Indirect parameters](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters) in the Clang ARC documentation:

> **Indirect parameters**
>
> If a function or method parameter has type `T*`, where `T` is an
>   ownership-unqualified retainable object pointer type, then:
>
> - if T is const-qualified or Class, then it is implicitly qualified with
>     __unsafe_unretained;
> - otherwise, it is implicitly qualified with `__autoreleasing`.

The second case applies here. And `__autoreleasing` means:

> For `__autoreleasing` objects, the new pointee is retained,
>   autoreleased, and stored into the lvalue using primitive semantics.

So `value` points to an autoreleased object upon return from that function.

The Xcode autocompletion "knows" this and shows

```
[scanner scanString:(NSString *) intoString:(NSString *__autoreleasing *)]
```

---

**Added:** For "manual reference counting", see [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) in the "Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide":

> **You Don’t Own Objects Returned by Reference**
>
> ... In these cases, the same rules apply as have already been described. When you invoke any of these methods, you do not create the NSError object, so you do not own it. There is therefore no need to release it, ...

Comment: @Atlas: Yes, I will update the answer with a reference to the documentation.